# Where am I wrong in understanding feedback network?

Tags: analog, cmos

The following is from the book [Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuit](https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf), Page 314.

Calculate the open-loop and closed-loop gains of the circuit shown in Fig. 8.66(a). Assume that λ = γ = 0.

[image]

For feedback network
consisting of \$R_S\$ and \$R_F\$,

$$h_{21} = -\frac{R_S} {R_S + R_F}$$

How did the author get this \$h_{21}\$?

The author has a similar example for this.

[image]

In this case, the feedback network is

$$g_{21} = \frac{R_S} {(R_F + R_S)}$$

**Similarly, we can also use this method for example 8.66.**

$$h_{21} = \frac{R_F} {R_S + R_F}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the linked document the terminology (A_open) and the used symbols (beta=h21) are somewhat confusing. More than that, to use an ideal current source to drive a MOSFET complicates the whole analysis. Nevertheless, I think that everything is correct.

At first, we should realize that we have **current-controlled feedback** and we need - at the same time - a **voltage** to drive the FET M1 in Fig. 8.66.

**1)** How works the feedback? The current source I_in drives the current through the Rf-path and creates a gate voltage at node Y (across Rs||1/g) which will be reduced by the voltage drop across Rs caused by the current I_out (no feeedback current through RF). **This describes the feedback effect** in words (180deg phase inversion due to common-source/common drain): Two currents with opposite sign meet in node Y and create the gate voltage for M1.

**2.)** My explanation starts with the well-known **classical feedback model** applied (as an example) to an inverting opamp (voltage-controlled current feedback). We will se that the used quantity "**Aopen**" in the linked doc needs an interpretation (because it is **NOT identical** to the opamps **open-loop gain Ao**).

**3.)** The closed-loop gain of the inverting opamp is **Acl=-(Hf * Ao)/[1+(Hr * Ao)]**

with forward damping **Hf=R2/(R1+R2)** and feedback factor **Hr=R1/(R1+R2)**.

For Ao approaching infinity we arrive at the well-known expression **Acl=-Hf/Hr=R2/R1**.

**4.)** Now let us compare the expression for the closed-loop expression in 3. with the closed-loop gain in the linked document (ignoring the negative sign):

**Acl=(Hf * Ao)/[1+(Hr * Ao)]=Aopen/(1+ h21 * Aopen)**

As we can see, both open-loop gain expressions are **not identical** because Aopen does not equal Ao. Therefore, the feedback factor **Hr** is **not identical** to the used feedback quantity **h21**.

The comparison gives: **Hr=h21 * Hf** or **h21=Hr/Hf**.

**5.)** Applying the (classical) definitions for Hf and Hr (see 3.) on the shown circuit in Fig. 8.66 we can write:

**Hr=Rs** (feedback voltage across Rs and no current through Rf) and **Hf=Rs+Rf** (input voltage caused by the signal source I_in).

Therefore: **h21=beta=Hr/Hf=Rs/(Rs+Rf)**.

(Because of current feedback the quantities Hf and Hr are not dimensionless; the are given in V/A).

**Comment**: From the circuit it was by simple visual inspection not evident to me that the feedback factor is Rs/(Rs+Rf). I think the reason is that (1) we have current-controlled feedback and (2) an input current source and - at the same time - a FET which does not consume any input current. And another reason was a definition for the gain without feedback (A_open) which - in contrast to the opamp example - contains also the input damping of the feedback network. Consequently, also the feedback factor beta=h21 has another definition if compared with the opamp example which I am more familiar with.

Finally, it must be mentioned that Razavis "A_open" is NOT identical to the commonly used term "loop gain".

**EDIT** : Upon request I have added the example circuit (inverter) and the corresponding block diagram (feedback model, Hf and Hr as defined in the text above).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It could be much better if you could you include several diagrams!

Comment: I think the feedback is negative in figure 8.54. Do you agree with me?

Comment: @kile The only circuit I have mentioned is the well-known opamp based inverter  - and I think, everybody knows how it looks like. Therefore ,I did not include a corresponding diagram.

Comment: @kile Following your request, I have added a drawing.

Comment: Thank you for your diagram. what kind of feedback do you think it is in Figure 8.54?

Comment: The feedback sigal is sampled from the output voltage of the second stage and controls - via a voltage divider - the input voltage (at the source node) of the 1st transistor. Hence, we have voltage-controlled voltage feedback.

Comment: I think this is negative feedback.  But the author said \$h_{21} = -R_S / (R_S + R_F)\$, closed-loop gain equals \$A_{I,open}/(1 + h_{21} A_{I,open})\$. which means \$\mbox{$\Large A_{I,close} = \frac{A_{I,open}} {1  -R_S / (R_S + R_F) A_{I,open}} $}\$. However, according to my analysis,  \$\mbox{$\Large A_{I,close} = \frac{A_{I,open}} {1  + R_S / (R_S + R_F) A_{I,open}} $}\$.

Comment: No doubt about this: We have negative feedback. But it does not matter if you assign the negative sign to the summing junction (feedback factor positiv) or to the feedback factor (summing junction with two positive signs). In both cases - and this applies to ALL negative feedback loops - there must be a "+" sign in the denominator of the closed-loop gain function.

Comment: Do you mean my  \$\mbox{$\Large A_{I,close} = \frac{A_{I,open}} {1  + R_S / (R_S + R_F) A_{I,open}} $}\$ is correct?

Comment: Yes, of course! As I have said: For negative feedback, there must be always a "+" sign in the denominator. This is because the closed loop gain in such a case is always lower than the gain without negative feedback.